# Text coloring based on the position of text

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm using AvalonEdit to create a textview which formats text like this:

Col 1 - Col 5 : FontStyle1 
Col 6 - Col 12: FontStyle2 
etc.

I've done this by overriding the ColorizeLine-Method of DocumentColorizingTransformer and then calling ChangeLinePart(...) for each segment of the line. It works, but for a large number of lines (~10000) it takes a very long time (> 10 seconds) to initialize the textview.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please add a general source code of how you are doing it.

Comment: The `DocumentColorizingTransformer` should only be getting called for lines that are currently visible; so I don't see why the time taken would depend on the document length. Check that you don't have a `ScrollViewer` or similar that allows the TextEditor to take infinite space -- this would cause it to render the whole document instead of just the visible portion.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did put the TextView inside a ScrollViewer. What would be the correct way to make it scrollable without using the ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to true solved the issue.